# Script to execute ssh-add with password on Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Every time after starting the system, I need to run a command:
`shh-add Documents/path/filename`
then enter the password:
`PaSsWORd`

Therefore, I wanted to write a script to automate this process.
I created a file with the .sh extension in the folder with the key and wrote the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh-add "filename"
```

But I had to enter the password manually. In order for the password to be entered automatically, I changed the script (sshpass i have installed):

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p "PaSsWORd" ssh-add "filename"
exit
```

But after running the script (script.sh) in the terminal the terminal freezes. It looks like it is hanging in an infinite loop.

What am I doing wrong and how can I execute the ssh-add command with a password?

Comment: Remove space after `-p`?

Comment: If you have the password for the ssh key in a bash script, you might as well make the ssh key password-less

Comment: Cyrus, removed the space after -p. It didn't help

Comment: `sshpass` supposed to enter authentication password, not a key protection password.